# How to check for changes in a file in PHP

Tags: php, multiplayer, inotify

I'm currently writing a multiplayer Connect 4 game. When a player makes a move, that move is written to a file containing the state of every position on the Connect 4 board.

I currently have a PHP script with a delayed loop that checks for changes since the previous loop iteration, and if there is a change, the PHP script returns the updated file to be sent to the player.

This method is extremely inefficient and messy; is there a better way to be instantly notified of changes in the game?

Also, I've tried to use inotify, however it doesn't seem to work on my server. (Mac OS X Server 10.8, so that's probably why...)

Comment: What kind of changes are you taking about ???

Comment: Why dont you use a mySQL database and record the changes there?

Comment: So why do you need to send updated files to the player? Can't you just re-render the page?

Comment: Why do you need a file use web sockets or cache system like memecache .

Comment: Because that would use unnecessary bandwidth. I could just poll the server using ajax every second or so, but I think that the file should only be sent if there are actual changes.

Comment: have you looked at ZeroMQ ??? You can actually push instead of pull ... You can also use a Worker which would only run process of sending to user only when there is a new request .. trust me they are so many better efficient way

Comment: @Sosumi That's what I meant. Re-render != refresh.

Comment: @Sosumi can i ask you how you send the file ... am sure i can look at work arounds

Comment: I use a method called 'long-polling', I think. The client has a jQuery ajax request which a large timeout. The PHP script that's requested only returns anything when there's a change to the file, however it does so inefficiently. This method gives the client new data as soon as its available, and wastes no bandwidth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be hard to it in PHP, how about using [node.js](http://nodejs.org)? It has these functions built right in.

Answer (score 0):

Polling in the background is not that uncommon for getting changes like this.  Can you be more specific about what you don't like?

If you are looking for something more clever, each player could open a keep-alive request asynchronously to a "game session" API.  The implementation could monitor the file for changes and send the next chunk when a change is detected.  Whether the change is from a file or DB is up to the server implementation.  Of course, your client application would need to make sure the request stays open and reconnect if it closes.